# Requirejs doesn't always load script when requested in an angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs, slick.js

I'm building an application using both AngularJS and RequireJS. I've used RequireJS many times before, but this is the first time in combination with Angular.

I'm using a slick.js slider that is initialized via a directive. About 30% of the time, slick is undefined in introBanner.init. Slick is exported but not always available.

**RequireJS loaded**

```
<script data-main="assets/scripts/main" src="assets/scripts/vendors/bower/require.js"></script>
```

**Main.js**

```
requirejs(['configuration'], function () {

'use strict';

require(['jquery', 'angular', 'foundation', 'foundation-templates', 'myMainJs'], function ($, angular, foundation) {

    //this manually inits/assigns the angular module to the document so the html ng-* attributes see it
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myMainJs']);

});

});
```

**configuration.js**

```
requirejs.config({
//baseUrl: '/assets/scripts',
paths: {
    'jquery': 'vendors/bower/jquery',
    'slick': 'vendors/bower/slick',
    'angular': 'vendors/bower/angular.min',
    'angular-ui-router': 'vendors/bower/angular-ui-router.min',
    'angular-animate': 'vendors/bower/angular-animate.min'
},

shim: {
    'slick': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'slick'
    },
    'angular-ui-router': {
        deps: ['angular'],
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular-animate': {
        deps: ['angular'],
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular'
    }
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="intro-banner" intro-banner>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x269');">
    <div class="slide-content">
        <h1 class="title">Lorem</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x269');">
    <div class="slide-content">
        <h1 class="title">Lorem</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
define(['jquery', 'slick'], function($, slick){

'use strict';

var introBanner = {
    init: function($elm) {

        $elm.slick({
            variableWidth: false,
            arrows: false,
            dots: true,
            autoplay: false
        });
    }
};

var introBannerDirective = function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            angular.element(elm).ready(function () {
                introBanner.init(elm);
            });
        }
    };
};

return introBannerDirective;

});
```

Comment: Please show the `script` elements that load RequireJS, configure RequireJS and start your application. Make sure to put them in the same order as in your actual HTML.

Comment: I already included the RequireJS config. I just added code showing where require is loaded and the application is started. Without those, require js scripts would never load, so I don't see why that is needed to help solve the problem because I said they load but not consistently.

Comment: You show the config but you don't explain how it becomes effective. If the RequireJS configuration is loaded by `requirejs(['configuration']`, then say this explicitly in your question because this is not a standard way to load the RequireJS configuration. (I never do it like this.)

Comment: The code for Require.js config is in a file called configuration.js